# OSX Cocoa NSCollectionViewFlowLayout horizontal scroll on zoom / magnification not working

Tags: swift, macos, cocoa, uicollectionviewlayout, nscollectionview

I want to make a zoom-able `NSCollectionView` in OSX. I use `NSCollectionViewFlowLayout` with a `vertical` flow and set `allow magnification` to true on `NSScrollView`, it works well. But one thing that I notice is that I cannot do horizontal scroll. Is this because the `NSCollectionViewFlowLayout` that prevents the horizontal scroll (Notice that I use `vertical` flow)? I did debug the view hierarchy and found out that the zoomed-view was clipped inside `NSClipView`, vertical scroll works, horizontal not. Any idea? Do I need to create a custom`NSCollectionViewFlowLayout` to do this?

Answer (score 0):

Try overriding:

```
@property NSCollectionViewScrollDirection scrollDirection;
```

on your NSCollectionViewFlowLayout subclass to return `NSCollectionViewScrollDirectionHorizontal`.

Comment: Hmm, I still need to be able to scroll in both direction, wouldn't it disable the vertical scroll?